# Pass variables in %run Databricks?

Tags: databricks

I'm trying to pass a variable, v, into a notebook I'm running that has a widget called name. I'd like to use something like the following:

```
%run /path/to/notebook $name=v
```

Obviously this code doesn't work, but is there a way to pass v into the %run? Currently I'm using dbutils.notebook.run() but got some resistance from the client because I'm returning everything back in a dictionary rather than directly getting access to the second notebook's variables from %run.

Comment: _"this code doesn't work,"_ --- elborate

Comment: @Kashyap you can’t pass v to $name. Let’s say v = “test”. Only thing I’ve been able to do is hard code $name=“test”. Obviously I don’t want to hard code it

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your notebook (`/path/to/notebook`) [has widgets](https://docs.databricks.com/en/notebooks/widgets.html) for input param.

[According to docs](https://docs.databricks.com/en/notebooks/widgets.html#widgets-and-percent-run) it's supported at least. Just need to quote the values?

```
%run /path/to/notebook $X="10" $Y="1"
```

Unless you're tied to `%run` API for some reason, I recommend use the [dbutils API](https://docs.databricks.com/en/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#dbutilsnotebook-api) instead. It should be a lot more precise.

```
dbutils.notebook.run("notebook-name", 60, {"argument": "data", "argument2": "data2", ...})
```

-- edit --

> since you can’t access notebook variables from a dbutils.notebook.run() command

What did you mean?

One notebook calling another notebook (`var-test1`), which calls another notebook (`var-test2`). Passing vars via widgets.

##### this notebook calls `var-test1`

[image]

##### this one (`var-test1`) adds `hello` to variable and calls `var-test2`

[image]

##### this one (`var-test2`) just prints final var value

[image]

Comment: I can’t hardcode the values in quotes. I need to pass it a variable. I currently am using the dbutils api, but since you can’t access notebook variables from a dbutils.notebook.run() command, I’m returning everything back as a dictionary, and the client is annoyed.

Comment: @almosthavoc not sure what you mean. Added some more to answer..